# react-beautiful-dnd update nested dropzone position

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

When I move the first element down, elements with nested dropzones change their position and their internal dropzones activate incorrectly. This only happens when an element is moved over a nested group. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

[example code](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/drag-drop-forked-jmtsnf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A15%2C51)

[correct behaviour image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YUJK.jpg)

[incorrect behaviour image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrkBW.jpg)

I tried adding a clone while dragging the element. This is not the best solution because It will cause dnd to work incorrectly in other cases.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.